# Bind [FromRoute] and [FromBody] into one model

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have this endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("company/{companyid}/bankaccount")]
public async Task<Unit> AddCompanyBankAccount([FromBody]AddCompanyBankAccountCommand request)
{
    return await _mediator.Send(request);
}
```

And model

```
public class AddCompanyBankAccountCommand : IRequest<Unit>
{
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string AccountNo { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public Guid CurrencyId { get; set; }
}
```

I would like my endpoint to be something like `POST contoso.com/company/{companyid}/bankaccount` and I want to bind the `{companyid}` as Guid from route to the model. Is this possible WITHOUT custom model binding? I'm using NET 6.0

I also saw this [website](https://www.thetechplatform.com/post/how-to-bind-fromroute-and-frombody-into-one-model-in-net-5), but it's not working for me

Comment: I can 't see and  int id in your view model. How are you going to bind 123 as Guid?

Comment: Try removing the `FromBody` annotation and pass valid `GUID` value in url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove all `FromXXX` attributes from your controller method parameter and instead use both parameters within the class itself. It would look then something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("company/{companyId:guid}/bankaccount")]
public async Task<Unit> AddCompanyBankAccount(AddCompanyBankAccountCommand request) { ... }

public class AddCompanyBankAccountCommand : IRequest<Unit>
{
    [FromRoute]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public BankAccount Account { get; set; }
}

public class BankAccount
{
    public string BankName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string AccountNo { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public Guid CurrencyId { get; set; }
}
```

Be aware that you change the model you use *inside* (cause you have a nested class now) while the public interface (in swagger) stays the same.

Also ensure to set the type constraint for guid in your route if your property is a guid.

Comment: this works! is it possible to avoid creating new class? That means i will have multiple `[FromBody]` in my property.

Comment: You can't have multiple `FromBodyAttribute` in one class or the behaviour is undefined (at least for me, cause I never tested that).

Answer (score 1):

I try the code and webside you provide, Because the type of `CompanyId` is `Guid`, So When I post `xxxx/company/8719AEDB-D34A-DAA3-E0C0-BA307F48F349/bankaccount`, As the website'method show, It can bind normally.

[image]

But, in your question, When you post `xxxxx/company/123/bankaccount`, you want bind `123` from route to the model, Because the type of `123` is `int`, the type of  `CompanyId` is `Guid`, Their types are differnet and You cannot convert Guid to int, So you can't bind them.

Comment: sorry i just realized i put `123`, please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The topic creator mentions that this [sample](https://www.thetechplatform.com/post/how-to-bind-fromroute-and-frombody-into-one-model-in-net-5) is not working for him.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]    
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase    
{        
    [HttpPut("{Id}")]
    public ActionResult<UserDto> Put(UserDtouserDto)        
    {
        return Ok(userDto);        
    }    
}

public class UserDto    
{        
    [FromRoute]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    [FromBody]
    public UserBodyDto Body { get; set; }    
}

public class UserBodyDto    
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteDish { get; set; }    
}
```

The sample works - but you have to **configure the `ApiBehaviorOptions`** in `Startup.cs` before!

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
});
```